# Blank plot with numeric data

Tags: plotting, numerical-value

I seem to be getting a blank plot even though the data provided is clearly numeric and plots fine with other data. I just don't see what is special about this data that results in a blank plot.

```
ListDensityPlot3D[{{0.`, -3.141592653589793`, -2.0943951023931953`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {0.5235987755982988`, -2.6179938779914944`, -2.0943951023931953`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {0.5235987755982988`, -3.141592653589793`, -1.5707963267948966`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {1.0471975511965976`, -2.6179938779914944`, -1.5707963267948966`, 
   0.7482264099176097`},
  {1.5707963267948966`, -2.0943951023931953`, -1.5707963267948966`, 
   0.916290731874155`},
  {2.0943951023931953`, -1.5707963267948966`, -1.5707963267948966`, 
   0.916290731874155`},
  {2.6179938779914944`, -1.0471975511965976`, -1.5707963267948966`, 
   0.7482264099176097`},
  {3.141592653589793`, -0.5235987755982988`, -1.5707963267948966`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {3.6651914291880923`, 0.`, -1.5707963267948966`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {4.1887902047863905`, 0.5235987755982988`, -1.5707963267948966`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-1.0471975511965976`, -5.235987755982989`, -1.0471975511965976`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-0.5235987755982988`, -4.71238898038469`, -1.0471975511965976`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {0.`, -4.1887902047863905`, -1.0471975511965976`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {0.5235987755982988`, -3.6651914291880923`, -1.0471975511965976`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {1.0471975511965976`, -3.141592653589793`, -1.0471975511965976`, 
   0.6931471805599453`}}, PlotRange -> Full, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

Out=[image: blankplot]

On the other hand, something like

```
ListDensityPlot3D[{{1.2566370614359172`, 
   1.2566370614359172`, -5.026548245743669`, 0.6931471805599453`},
  {1.8849555921538759`, -4.39822971502571`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {2.5132741228718345`, -3.7699111843077517`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {3.141592653589793`, -3.141592653589793`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {3.7699111843077517`, -2.5132741228718345`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {4.39822971502571`, -1.8849555921538759`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-1.2566370614359172`, -1.2566370614359172`, -5.026548245743669`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-0.6283185307179586`, -0.6283185307179586`, -5.026548245743669`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {0.`, 0.`, -5.026548245743669`, 0.6931471805599453`},
  {0.6283185307179586`, 0.6283185307179586`, -5.026548245743669`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {1.8849555921538759`, 1.2566370614359172`, -4.39822971502571`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-3.7699111843077517`, 1.8849555921538759`, 1.8849555921538759`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-3.141592653589793`, 2.5132741228718345`, 1.8849555921538759`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-2.5132741228718345`, 3.141592653589793`, 1.8849555921538759`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-1.8849555921538759`, 3.7699111843077517`, 1.8849555921538759`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-1.2566370614359172`, -1.8849555921538759`, -4.39822971502571`, 
   0.6931471805599453`},
  {-0.6283185307179586`, -1.2566370614359172`, -4.39822971502571`, 
   0.6931471805599453`}}, PlotRange -> Full, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

plots perfectly fine.

Out=[image: okplot]

Any help would be appreciated. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The points are all in a plane, and mostly all on a line. `ListDensityPlot3D` seems to not like that.

You could roll your own by drawing and coloring some polygons:

```
data = {{0.`,-3.141592653589793`,-2.0943951023931953`,0.6931471805599453`},{0.5235987755982988`,-2.6179938779914944`,-2.0943951023931953`,0.6931471805599453`},{0.5235987755982988`,-3.141592653589793`,-1.5707963267948966`,0.6931471805599453`},{1.0471975511965976`,-2.6179938779914944`,-1.5707963267948966`,0.7482264099176097`},{1.5707963267948966`,-2.0943951023931953`,-1.5707963267948966`,0.916290731874155`},{2.0943951023931953`,-1.5707963267948966`,-1.5707963267948966`,0.916290731874155`},{2.6179938779914944`,-1.0471975511965976`,-1.5707963267948966`,0.7482264099176097`},{3.141592653589793`,-0.5235987755982988`,-1.5707963267948966`,0.6931471805599453`},{3.6651914291880923`,0.`,-1.5707963267948966`,0.6931471805599453`},{4.1887902047863905`,0.5235987755982988`,-1.5707963267948966`,0.6931471805599453`},{-1.0471975511965976`,-5.235987755982989`,-1.0471975511965976`,0.6931471805599453`},{-0.5235987755982988`,-4.71238898038469`,-1.0471975511965976`,0.6931471805599453`},{0.`,-4.1887902047863905`,-1.0471975511965976`,0.6931471805599453`},{0.5235987755982988`,-3.6651914291880923`,-1.0471975511965976`,0.6931471805599453`},{1.0471975511965976`,-3.141592653589793`,-1.0471975511965976`,0.6931471805599453`}};
points = data[[All, ;; 3]];
values = data[[All, 4]];

Graphics3D[{
  EdgeForm[],
  Polygon[points, 
   VertexColors -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ values]
  }, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you could project onto a plane and then plot. One way is to use `DimensionReduce`:

```
points2D = DimensionReduce[points]

(* {{0.049659, -2.06735}, {-0.379941, -1.87048}, {0.461743, -0.55237}, \
{0.0321432, -0.355496}, {-0.397457, -0.158622}, {-0.827057, 
  0.0382519}, {-1.25666, 0.235126}, {-1.68626, 0.431999}, {-2.11586, 
  0.628873}, {-2.54546, 0.825747}, {2.59223, 0.175115}, {2.16263, 
  0.371989}, {1.73303, 0.568863}, {1.30343, 0.765737}, {0.873828, 
  0.962611}} *)

ListDensityPlot[Transpose@Append[Transpose@points2D, values], PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the x, y, z coordinates you'll see the problematic data is two-dimensional.

[image]